# ¿Cómo lograr en un componente cliente TIDTCPClient un _evento_ similar al Execute del Server en Delphi?

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy

En un sistema transaccional se requiere conectarse como cliente a un Server de otro sistema y dar respuesta a mensajes de solicitud del server.

¿Cómo se puede emular el evento OnExecute con el componente TIDTCPClient de Indy en Delphi?

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varios aspectos que *cubre* el evento `OnExecute` del componente 
`TidTCPServer`, y en mi opinión, no eres lo suficientemente específico sobre cuál de esos comportamientos quieres conseguir *emular*.

Supondré que lo que buscas es que de manera *automática* se *detecte* si hay datos para leer y se lance un *evento* que pueda realizar la lectura de estos datos, por lo que mi respuesta cubre este aspecto de la manera más sencilla que se me puede ocurrir.

## Consideraciones iniciales

Antes de desarrollar mi respuesta, acoto de una vez que el componente `TidTCPServer` es un componente MultiHilos, que el evento OnExecute ocurre en el contexto de un hilo secundario, y por tanto sus *actividades* se realizan *en background* (a menos que se programe lo contrario). No estoy intentando repetir este comportamiento (por simplicidad de la solución). Además, siendo un servidor, pueden haber varios `OnExecute` ejecutándose a la vez, uno por cada cliente conectado, esto sería *imposible* de replicar en un `TidTCPClient`, pues el cliente puede establecer una única conexión a un único servidor.

## Solución simple en el hilo principal

Dicho esto, la solución *fácil* sería establecer la conexión y, a partir de allí, revisar constantemente si hay datos que *leer* del servidor. Podemos realizar esto, por ejemplo, con un TTimer. Cada vez que haya datos, reaccionamos a ese *evento* de manera apropiada y luego continuamos periódicamente a la espera de más datos.

Preparé y ejecuté un ejemplo, dónde componente cliente tiene un ReadTimeout de 100 ms. para evitar que la aplicación se quede detenida mucho tiempo esperando información. El servidor envía *comandos*, que son cadenas de texto terminadas en CRLF, con un saludo, un contador y la hora a la que se envió el mensaje. Para cada *comando* el cliente añade el contenido a un memo prefijando la hora a la que el comando fue recibido. El timer se ejecuta cada segundo.

El código relevante del cliente es este:

```
procedure TForm1.bConectarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdTCPClient1.Connect;
  tmrComandosServidor.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.bDesconectarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  tmrComandosServidor.Enabled := False;
  IdTCPClient1.DisconnectNotifyPeer;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPClient1Status(ASender: TObject; const AStatus: TIdStatus;
  const AStatusText: string);
begin
  if AStatus = TIdStatus.hsDisconnected then
    tmrComandosServidor.Enabled := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.tmrComandosServidorTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(0) then
  begin
    try
      Memo1.Lines.Add(FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss:zzz', Now) + ' '
        + IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn());
    except
      on E:EidReadTimeout do
        ;  //No había aún suficientes datos para leer un comando, 
           //no pasa nada, en la siguiente iteración lo pillamos.
    end;
  end;
end;
```

En tiempo de corrida, luce como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Otras posibilidades

Dicho esto, podrías también realizar, de manera análoga a lo que hace ya el componente servidor de Indy, toda esta acción en un hilo secundario. De hecho, pensando *orientado a objetos*, podrías realizar un componente que internamente tenga un TidTCPClient y que ya incorpore la funcionalidad de realizar todas estas acciones en un hilo secundario, y lanzar un evento a la interfaz de usuario cada vez que haya datos nuevos (que es básicamente lo que ocurre tras bambalinas del *OnExecute*).

Esta entre, quizás, muchas otras alternativas de solución, que quedan fuera del alcance de esta corta respuesta.

Comment: jachguate, agradezco la colaboración prestada.
Hay más claridad en el tema.